# Forcing ArcGIS iOS to use GPS data from External GPS device?

Tags: gps, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I created an app that will display the map and the location of the external GPS device. The scenario is using a wifly module to broadcast the GPS data of the GPS receiver in wifi. The app is now receiving the data from the wifly module.

How do i force ArcGIS to use the data from the wifly module?

I am using the AGSLocationDisplay of ArcGIS iOS but its using the data from the CLLocation.

Comment: You are not going to find a simple switch to enable this, you will need to use the ArcGIS API for IOS to access the other device via network connection (wifi in your case) to get to the exposed interface. It sounds like you have done the hardest part already, getting the devices to talk, you just will need to create a new interface to read that input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply D.E Wright. I just dont know where to start. I was actually planning to not use the ArcGIS location display and probably just create a point from the coordinates retrieved from the wifly dongle.

Answer (score 3):

With the 10.1.1 version of ArcGIS SDK you can replace the `AGSLocationDisplay` object's data source that `AGSMapView` uses with your own location data source.  You don't have to rely on `CLLocationManager` as a GPS data source.  You'll be able to get GPS location data from anywhere you want.

First, create an object that conforms to the `AGSLocationDisplayDataSource` protocol ([defined here.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/apiref/protocol_a_g_s_location_display_data_source-p.html))  This object will need to get data from your wifly module (how I don't know) and return it when called.  It needs to conform to the `AGSLocationDisplayDataSource` protocol:

```
@interface WiflyDataSource <AGSLocationDisplayDataSource> : NSObject
...
```

Second, on your `AGSMapView` object (let's call it `mapView`), there is a property called `locationDisplay`, it has a property called `dataSource`.  Set `dataSource` with your object, like this:

```
WiflyDataSource* wiflyDataSource = [WiflyDataSource alloc] initWith...];  
mapView.locationDisplay.dataSource = wiflyDataSource;
```

Now the `mapView` will get location updates from your data source instead of the default one which uses `CLLocationManager`.